# Using a file returned from a function as an argument for another function in python

Tags: python

I am trying to use a `.txt` file written by a function in another function which accepts an `os.path`-like object. My problem is when I feed the argument it shows me the error message

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper

The following is the simple form of what I am trying to do.

```
def myfunction1(infile, outfile):
    with open(infile, 'r') as firstfile:
      #do stuff
    with open(outfile, 'w+') as  secondfile:
       secondfile.write(stuff)
    return(outfile) 

def myfucntion2(infile, outfile):
    infile=myfunction1(infile, outfile)
    with open(infile, 'r') as input:
        #do stuff
    with open (outfile, 'w+') as outfile2:
        outfile2.write(stuff)
    return(outfile)
```

Both functions do stuff fine on their own, it's just that I can't seem to feed 2nd function a value from the first.

Comment: I tried to fix the indentation but that is obviously speculative -- please review. Also I imagine you want to `open(infile)` not `open('infile') in `myfunction1`.

Comment: Also, `2ndfile`? That's not a valid variable name. How does that run at all to give you that TypeError?

Comment: sorry about the typos, tried to write simple version quickly. original code was too long to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns a file *handle,* not a string.

File handles have a `name` attribute, so you could fix it by using `return (outfile.name)` in `myfunction1` if that's really what you mean; or you could use `infile = myfunction1(infile, outfile).name` in `myfunction2` if that's more suitable for your scenario.  Or, since what is returned is the result from `open`, just don't attempt to `open` it a second time -- just use the returned file handle directly.

```
input=myfunction1(infile, outfile)
#do stuff
with open (outfile, 'w+') as outfile2 ...
```

In summary: `open` wants a string containing a file name as its input, and returns a file handle. You can retrieve the string which represents the file name of an open file with `open(thing).name`.

Comment: thanks ```infile = myfunction1(infile, outfile).name``` solves the problem.